# Группировка по двум колонкам

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица со списком сообщений на сайте, в которой имеются два столбца: Автор и Получатель. Необходимо выбрать из таблицы все последние сообщения для заданного пользователя, который может фигурировать как Автор, так и Получатель. Т.е. если мы находим 2 записи, в первой пользователь является автором, а во второй с тем же самым собеседником является получателем, то нам нужна только последняя запись.

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: я когда-то что-то похожее писал, посмотрите, может поможет - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342835/get-last-message-from-each-conversation/34343416#34343416

Comment: Уточните структуру таблицы

Answer (score 2):

В MySQL можно сделать так:

```
SELECT MSGs.*
FROM MSGs
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN user_from < user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END id1, 
    CASE WHEN user_from > user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END id2, 
    MAX(send_time) max_time
  FROM MSGs
  --автор или получатель
  WHERE @UserId = user_from OR @UserId = user_to
  --группируем по двум столбцам
  GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN user_from < user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END, 
    CASE WHEN user_from > user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END 
)T --соединяем по автору/получателю и времени сообщения
  ON send_time = max_time
  AND CASE WHEN user_from < user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END = id1
  AND CASE WHEN user_from > user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END = id2
WHERE @UserId = user_from OR @UserId = user_to
```

В MS SQL, Oracle, PG SQL было бы проще:

```
SELECT user_from, user_to, send_time
FROM(
  SELECT MSGs.*,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY 
      CASE WHEN user_from < user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END, 
      CASE WHEN user_from > user_to THEN user_from ELSE user_to END
      ORDER BY send_time DESC
    ) N
  FROM MSGs
  --автор или получатель
  WHERE @UserId = user_from OR @UserId = user_to
)T
WHERE N=1
```